# KineticJS polygon multiple stroke colors

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

Is it possible to have multiple stroke colors for a KineticJS regular polygon?

Here is a fiddle of just a regular pentagon http://jsfiddle.net/BrianSpry/wNT4D/. Essentially I want to be able to have a

```
    stroke: 'insert different color'
```

for each of the 5 sides, however I do not know if that is easily possible with KineticJs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular polygon shape can only have 1 stroke color.

As a workaround, you can use a Kinetic.Group containing 5 Kinetic.Lines with different fill colors to assemble a 5 colored pentagon.

Comment: Thanks markE!  I really appreciate the effort you put into answering the KineticJS questions, it really helps out new guys like me!